# In extjs4,how to maintain expand and collapse state of panel

Tags: extjs4, state

I am working in extjs4. I have collapsible panel as=

```
            xtype: 'panel',     
            autoHeight : true,
            border: false,
            itemId : 'dashmetrics',
            frame: false,
            cls : 'matrix-tab-panel-container',
            bodyCls : 'matrix-tab-panel-container-body',
            layout: 'form',
            title : 'Panel1'
            collapsible : true,
            titleCollapse : true,
            padding:'3px 0 3px 0',
            stateful: true,
            getState: function() {
                  return {
                     collapsed: this.collapsed
                  };
            },
            applyState : function(state){
                if(state){
                    Ext.apply(this, state);
                }
            },
            stateEvents: ['collapse', 'expand']
```

i want to maintain state of this expand and collapse. I tried as above, But is getState() is always returning false. So how to maintain panel's collapse and expand state in extjs4?

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.state.Stateful-cfg-stateful

Comment: can you clarify what you mean? Maintain state across page refresh or based on some stored server side value?

Comment: yaa i need to maintain state across page refresh. So that if last time panel is in collapsed state, i want to show same panel on refresh in same state i.e. in collapse condition.